# Complex conversions of a website to PDF

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, acrobat

Is there a way to generate a PDF from a website that will be formatted into pages and a standard size eg A4? I'm looking into the possibility of creating a CMS based site that a client can edit, once they've edited it they can generate a high quality PDF to use as an offline presentation tool.

Is there a way to have a high level of control over a PDF output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use wordpress cms there is a plugin which will convert your document to PDF and you are asking about A4 size it's only based on the printing.
You can get that  plugin [here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/convert-to-pdf)